# How can I compare lists and repeat a task till the lists from previous and current iteration are equal?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, conditional-statements, do-while

I want to append elements to two separate lists. It should continue till set(list1 of previous iteration) == set(list1 of this iteration), and set(list2 of previous iteration) == set(list2 of this iteration). So far I have this. It's looping infinitely, and I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

while True:
    prev_list1 = []
    prev_list2 = []
    for x in my_list:
        if x == 'A':
            list1.append(x)
        elif x == 'B':
            list2.append(x)

    if set(list1) == set(prev_list1) and set(list2) == set(prev_list2):
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I spotted the mistake. I was not updating the previous lists!

```
while True:
    prev_list1 = list1
    prev_list2 = list2
```